# Why do I receive a plain text email when I send it as HTML?

Tags: .net, email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am sending test emails to my gmail account, using the BCL `SmtpClient`. The `MailMessage` I send has an HTML body, with `IsBodyHtml` being true, and one `AlternateView` that is plain text. When I view the received mail online, gmail only gives me the plain text version. Is this an issue with gmail, or is there something I should be doing when I send the mail?

The original mail is also on a gmail account, and when I open it there, I see the expected HTML version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the plain-text AlternateView after adding the HTML view, then the plain-text view will take precedence.

In a `multipart/alternative` message, the last part in the list has the highest level of preference. The first view has the lowest level of preference.

Comment: That's not generally true. Do you have a reference for this statement? Are you saying it's true for Gmail in particular? (I'm not very familiar with  their web interface.)

Comment: From rfc2046: In this case, the alternatives appear in an order of increasing faithfulness to the original content. In general, the best choice is the LAST part of a type supported by the recipient system's local environment.

Comment: The HTML view is the main view, i.e. not an `AlternateView` object on the `MailMessage` but its actual `Body`. I'm guessing the problem may be because the body is created first, then the `AlternateView` added later. Either that or `SmtpClient` doesn't care which order it sends the parts in.

Comment: Take a look at the raw message source. That's the only way to tell.

Comment: Most modern clients I have seen have a user preference which trumps this logic.  It usually defaults to HTML, but you can set it to always prefer plain text.  Perhaps the question should also indicate which client the OP is using.